# Select null on a join where a record doesn't exist in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I've got a problem that I can't seem to figure out after a bunch of failed attempts.

I've got three tables that I need to do a join on for some reporting, and in the 2nd table a record might not exist. If the record doesn't exist, I need to report a null value for the data that comes from the 3rd table.

In the most basic form, here are the table structures (it's for a survey)

```
Table A (Survey)
-----------------------
SurveyNumber | SurveyId
016243023708   1152010

Table B (Response)
----------------------------------
SurveyId | QuestionId | ResponseId
1152010    1279235      486

Table C (Response Values)
--------------------
ResponseId | Value
486          Yes
```

To explain why a record may not exist in Table B is simply because the values are inserted as the survey is completed. If the user leaves the survey without finishing (they can come back later), the record in Table B won't be there. The value in table C should be reported as null for this.

If it makes it any easier, I need to do the reporting specifically for questionid 1279235.

This is the query I've come up with so far (it shows me everything but the surveys with a missing record in table b for question 1279235).

```
SELECT      A.SurveyNumber, A.SurveyId, B.QuestionID, C.Value
FROM        tblA A
LEFT JOIN   tblB B
        ON  A.SurveyId = B.SurveyId
LEFT JOIN   tblC C
        ON  B.ResponseId = C.ResponseId 
WHERE       B.QuestionId = 1279235
```

I can provide more clarification if it is needed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you put a filter on an outer table in the where clause, you've turned the outer join into an inner join. The correct way to filter an outer table is to make the filter criteria part of the join, not the where. I think both answers do that correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT
    A.SurveyNumber, A.SurveyId, B.QuestionID, C.Value
    FROM tblA        A
    LEFT JOIN tblB   B ON  A.SurveyId=B.SurveyId AND B.QuestionId=1279235
    LEFT JOIN tblC   C ON  B.ResponseId=C.ResponseId
```

**EDIT** working example:

```
DECLARE @tblA  table (SurveyNumber varchar(12),SurveyId int)
INSERT INTO @tblA VALUES ('016243023708',   1152010)
INSERT INTO @tblA VALUES ('016243023708',   1152011)

DECLARE @tblB table (SurveyId int, QuestionId int, ResponseId int)
INSERT INTO @tblB values (1152010,    1279235,      486)
INSERT INTO @tblB values (1152011,    1279235,      487)

DECLARE @tblC  table (ResponseId int, ValueOf varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @tblC values (486,          'Yes')


SELECT
    A.SurveyNumber, A.SurveyId, B.QuestionID, C.ValueOf
    FROM @tblA        A
    LEFT JOIN @tblB   B ON  A.SurveyId=B.SurveyId AND B.QuestionId=1279235
    LEFT JOIN @tblC   C ON  B.ResponseId=C.ResponseId
```

OUTPUT:

```
SurveyNumber SurveyId    QuestionID  ValueOf
------------ ----------- ----------- ----------
016243023708 1152010     1279235     Yes
016243023708 1152011     1279235     NULL

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 10):

do not put the condition in the where clause, but instead on the join part since records on `tablec` may not exist.

```
SELECT      A.SurveyNumber, A.SurveyId, B.QuestionID, C.Value
FROM        tblA A
            LEFT JOIN   tblB B
                  ON  A.SurveyNumber = B.SurveyNumber AND 
                      B.QuestionId = 1279235
            LEFT JOIN   tblC C
                  ON  B.ResponseId = C.ResponseId
```